# Compiler Problems on MAUI RC1

Tags: maui

I have an app that I started using the out of the box MAUI project template.  I have been running it on both a local Android emulator and a remote Mac emulator.  It had been working on both, and then today after running it on Android for a while, I changed the debugger to use the Mac emulator.  It immediately refused to compile, and listed every Android class reference as "type or namespace [blah] could not be found".  After playing with several things, I found that if I commented out the "using Java.Net" on the default MainPage.xaml.cs, all of the compiler errors went away.  If I uncomment it again, then all 20 something compiler errors show up again.  This is the out of the box MainPage.xaml that came with the project template, plus one click event handler that I added - is there some known issue here?

As I said, it was working fine for nearly two weeks, and then just went bananas on me today.  Haven't added any nuget packages or anything like that - just been writing code.

Thanks.

Comment: "Remote mac emulator": emulating Android or iOS or what?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are on RC1. The RC3 is the latest

Comment: Using RC1 because that's what I downloaded a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've described the issue in your question:

> `using "Java.Net"` on the default MainPage.xaml.cs.

That won't compile for any platform except Android.

It doesn't exist on the default MainPage.xaml.cs (which you could have verified by creating a new project).

My recommendation: **Start over** with a fresh project. Add again whatever you added, and see if that `using` appears again. If it does, you've added something **Android specific**. Which doesn't make sense, on a cross-platform page.

If `using` does appear again, and you don't understand why, then add to your question the exact code which, when added to page, causes `using Java.net;` to appear.

If you were following some example, also add a link to the example web page.

---

**UPDATE**

I have a theory about how that `using` got there:

I bet you added a reference to some class which exists in [`Java.net` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.net?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12).
So Visual Studio gave you an option to add a "using".

If that happens again, and a "using" mentions `Android` or `Java`, DON'T add the `using`, UNLESS you are in a file inside your project's `Platforms/Android` folder.

Some **class names** exist **both** in an Android or Java namespace, **and** in a .Net or Maui namespace. In cross-platform code, pick the cross-platform `using`, not the platform-specific one. If they are in different namespaces, they are different classes - even if the names are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm honestly not sure how it got in there.  The ironic thing is that it is greyed out (i.e. there's not even anything using it).  I tried commenting out all of the code, then uncommenting it in chunks to see if anything caused it to light up, but nothing did.  This is the second project in which this has happened, so I'm just going to try and keep a closer eye on when/if it gets added.